# Problems with youtube videos

Tags: youtube-api

I am not getting feed from youtube API URL.

I have channel on youtube as follows:

```
https://www.youtube.com/user/keyurmistry53
```

and trying to fetch video from that but not getting any video for the feed. Following is the feed URL.

`http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=keyurmistry53&start-index=1&max-results=25`

Can anyone tell me that what is issue with that?

Answer (score 0):

Using the url's given, the api feed shows only 2 videos, while the channel on YouTube shows more than 2. Check the video settings for any difference. The api url is for api version 2 which is deprecated. See for api version 3: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started

Your url, http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=keyurmistry53&start-index=1&max-results=25 , shows 2 videos, which are (Not showing complete feed data):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'>
    <entry>
        <title type='text'>Tera Milna Sonu Nigam</title>
        <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwRoUHqn9Pw&amp;feature=youtube_gdata'/>
        <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.related' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/pwRoUHqn9Pw/related'/>
        <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#mobile' type='text/html' href='http://m.youtube.com/details?v=pwRoUHqn9Pw'/>
        <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/pwRoUHqn9Pw'/>
        <author>
            <name>Keyur Mistry</name>
            <uri>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/keyurmistry53</uri>
        </author>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title type='text'>Gujarati Savariyo Re maro</title>
        <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4XA4mLZcAU&amp;feature=youtube_gdata'/>
        <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.related' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/D4XA4mLZcAU/related'/>
        <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#mobile' type='text/html' href='http://m.youtube.com/details?v=D4XA4mLZcAU'/>
        <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/D4XA4mLZcAU'/>
        <author>
            <name>Keyur Mistry</name>
            <uri>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/keyurmistry53</uri>
        </author>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

When you get no feed at all, then it seems there is something wrong with your code, but not with the url used.